# Does ReactJS have a binding for input fields?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a (reasonably complex) form in react that in a pared-down form looks like this:

```
var MyForm = React.createClass({
    init: { data: { "MyValue" : "initial value" } },
    getInitialState: function() {
        return this.init;
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
        this.setState({data: this.props.basedata });
    },
    save: function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var d = this.state.data;
        console.log(ev, d, d.MyValue)
    },
    render: function () {
      if(this.state.data === null){ return; }
      var d = this.state.data;
      return (
        <div>
          <form>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value" defaultValue={d.MyValue}  />
            <button onClick={this.save}>Save</button>
          </form>
          <div>{d.MyValue}</div>
        </div>);
    }
});

var dataObject = { "MyValue" : "external value" }
ReactDOM.render( <MyForm basedata={dataObject} />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

(available as a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/achesser/d8veuvnh/1/)

Does react have a "built in" way of ensuring that the value of `d.MyValue` is updated to the value within the input box at the time I click "save"? or do I have to write an OnChange handler for each input?

Comment: Yes you have to write for each input element. React doesn't have anything  like `bind` an Angular.

Answer (score 0):

I've update the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d8veuvnh/2/) , I bound {d.MyValue} to the html value property in stead of the defaultValue:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    init: { data: { "MyValue" : "initial value" } },
    getInitialState: function() {
        return this.init;
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
        this.setState({data: this.props.basedata });
    },
    save: function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var d = this.state.data;
        console.log(ev, d, d.MyValue)
    },
    render: function () {
      if(this.state.data === null){ return; }
      var d = this.state.data;
      return (
        <div>
          <form>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value" value={d.MyValue} />
            <button onClick={this.save}>Save</button>
          </form>
          <div>{d.MyValue}</div>
        </div>);
    }
});

var dataObject = { "MyValue" : "external value" }

ReactDOM.render( <Hello basedata={dataObject} />, document.getElementById('container'));
```